# What is the farthest distance a vertice of the smaller square could be from a vertice of the big square?

Tags: geometry

A square with perimeter of 20 is inscribed in another square of 28.

My guess is $4 \sqrt{10}$. The side of the large square is divided into segments of 3 and 4. Is there any other possibility?

Comment: If the other square has perimeter $27$, the expression more complicated than the guess mentioned, which is larger than the diagonal of the big square.

Comment: Here.i edited .

Comment: Based on your guess, I am assuming you meant to write the smaller ("inner") square has perimeter of 20, not 25 -- correct?  Then splitting the sides of the large square into segments of 3 and 4 produces 3-4-5 triangles which form the inner square.  But the distance sought would then be only $\sqrt{65}$...  There is definitely something wrong with the way this question is posed; as @AndréNicolas noted, the distance you are guessing is larger than the diagonal of the big square.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, there is definitely something wrong with the way this question is posed, as the numbers simply are not consistent with one another.  However, here is a general method for solving problems of this type.

**Problem:** A large square with side length $A$ has a smaller square of side length $B$ inscribed inside it.  Find the maximum distance from a vertex of the smaller square to a vertex of the larger square.

**Solution**:  Suppose the vertices of the small square divide each side of the large square into segments of length $x$ and $y$.  Then we have $x+y=A$, but also $x^2 + y^2 = B^2$.  Solve this system (for example, by substituting $y=A-x$ into the second equation and then using the quadratic formula to solve for $x$) and find the values of $x$ and $y$.  Without loss of generality, let $x$ denote the longer of the two segments.  Then the maximum distance from a vertex of the smaller square to a vertex of the larger square is given by $\sqrt{x^2+A^2}$.

Comment: How you got this expression?

Comment: Why isn't $B$ there?

Comment: Draw a picture.  The distance from a vertex of the smaller square to the farthest vertex of the larger square is the hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides $A$ and $x$.